# How can I influence the redirect behavior in a play-controller?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

In play you always follow the [Redirect-After-Post-Pattern](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post) if you call from a public-method of a controller. This is in most cases a good behavior, but sometime it could be nasty.
So I tried to find out how it works in play 1.1!:
The basic is some byte-code-enhancement, which is done in `play.classloading.enhancers.ControllersEnhancer`. 
There you can find that there still exists some exceptions of the default behavior:

1. If your method is annotated by an annotation from the package `play.mvc`, for example the Before-annotation.
2. You annotate your action with the `ByPass`-Annotation, this Annotation must be an inner-class so the name endsWith `$ByPass`.

Both solutions are fine if you always want to suppress the redirect. But what if you only want to do it in special situation?
Then you can call `ControllerInstrumentation.initActionCall()`.

I don't find a description about it, I just analyze the code. So are my conclusion correct or have the any drawbacks?

Comment: initActionCall is indeed useful if you need to call another view but do not want to redirect: http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/59c2aebefb94aac5/62651072b74275e1?lnk=gst&q=redirect#3f5ccb63d4652565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I know you assumptions are correct.

That said, for what I understand you want a method that ends after execution and returns nothing? Don't add any "render" call at the end (or any call to another method) and that should work. I use it for cron jobs.