# Calling static methods in Play! framework controller doesn't work

Tags: java, playframework, static-methods

I have a Play! framework with two actions which contain redundant code. So I factored this code into a `private static` method, but It doesn't work anymore then.

```
  public static void show(long itemId, String listId) {
    render(getItem(itemId, listId));
  }

  private static Item getItem(long itemId, String listId) {
    // otherwise duplicate code ...
    return item;
  }
```

If I inline the code contained in `getItem` into the `show` action everything is fine:

```
  // this works
  public static void show(long itemId, String listId) {
    Item item = // duplicate code ...
    render(item);
  }
```

Why can I not call other static methods within a Play! controller?

**Solution**

Thanks to 'Codemwnci' I've implemented the following solution:

```
  public static void show(long itemId, String listId) {
    renderArgs.put("item", getItem(itemId, listId));
    render();
  }
```

I prefer `renderArgs` because it makes the intention more clear than a local variable.

Comment: Have in mind that if you make the helper-method public a redirect is happened. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899670/how-can-i-influence-the-redirect-behavior-in-a-play-controller. This isn't your problem now, but could be the next, where some magic happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a local variable into the render method, the name of the local variable is used when passed through to the Groovy view. In your example, you are not passing a local variable, therefore Play does not know what name to give the item you have specified.

You have a couple of options. You can do either

1. Set the return from getItem to a local variable (item), and pass item into the view
2. Set the return from getItem into the renderArgs map, and specify your own name.

Option 1 is probably the most sensible.

Comment: it is one of the things that is intended to be addressed in Play2.0, but this convention does significantly reduce code by not having to map variables from controllers into the view