# Play Framework: Best practice for validation errors redirect

Tags: java, playframework

I am implementing a project with play 1.2.4, based on documentation the right way to handle validation is:

```
public static void signUp() {
    render();
}

public static void doSignUp(@Required @Valid User user) {
    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        params.flash();
        validation.keep();
        signUp();
    }
    user.create();
    Application.index();
}
```

But based on samples provided with play, it seems that different approach is used:

```
public static void signUp() {
    render();
}

public static void doSignUp(@Required @Valid User user) {
    if (validation.hasErrors()) {
        render("@signUp"); 
    }
    user.create();
    Application.index();
}
```

For this small example the code difference is small, but in more complex examples it's not so simple.

Pros and cons I see are:
First approach:

- Gives nice URLs to user
- Always redirects after POST, so no confirm problem if user refreshes page
- Only one method is responsible for filling renderArgs before calling
  template
- Compile time verification that signUp method exits if it gets renamed

Second approach:

- Faster, no redirect/round-trip in browser

So what is the best practice? Which approach to use use along the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me go over your arguments:

First:

> Gives nice URLs to user

The URL can always be fine in Play 1.x. You can use the following:

```
get  /signUp  myController.signUp
post /signUp  myController.doSignUp
```

So the first argument doesn't matter.

Second:

> Always redirects after POST, so no confirm problem if user refreshes page.

I think if a user makes a mistake and press F5 or refresh with other technique it's good if he get the same errors again. If the user should get the possibility to get a clean form, I prefer to have a cancel-button.

Third:

> Only one method is responsible for filling renderArgs before calling template

Can't see the problem with `render("@signUp");`

Fourth:

> Compile time verification that signUp method exits if it gets renamed.

Ok, this is an argument but I think it's weak. Will be false with play 2.0.

So I think both approaches can be good, depending on the situation. Specially if you have a large form, the redirect won't work. As default I would recommend the second solution.
However, I don't know how the situation with play 2.0 will be.

Comment: For URLs I know about play routes, worst case apache with mod_rewrite is always available. But for now we would like to keep all url configurations only using convention from method and class name. This way it's easy for someone new to find method just from url.

For render("@signUp"), I don't see anything about it in documentation, only renderTemplate, my understanding is that it just renders template from signUp, not calls signUp controller method? If so, then everything we do in signUp controllers to fill renderArgs, needs to be done again.

Comment: If you want to use convention over configuration you can do the following:
get  /{controller}/{action}  {controller}.{action}
post /{controller}/{action}  {controller}.do{action}

Comment: Ok the last comment become broken, I can't edit it:<br/>If you want to use convention over configuration you can do the following:
<code>
    get  /{controller}/{action}  {controller}.{action}
    post /{controller}/{action}  {controller}.do{action}
</code>
ok dosingup is not so nice like doSignup.<br/>
The @signUp is as far as I know simple the the template-name, so mycontroller/signup.html.<br/>
At last the hint that the generic approach won't work with Play2.0

Comment: Right, thanks, but that means if I (for example) want to prepare list of possible option for some select option on sign up, and list depends on user IP (just an example). I will have some code that calculated that list and then calls renderArgs.put("options", optionsFromIp). Then I will have to also call this logic in "post" handler and also call renderArgs.put() before I call render("@signup"). Bigger problem here is someone later changes this code in signup(), but not in doSignup, or adds new renderArgs and then he needs to know to add it in second method. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct. However you must handle the form data-correctly too. If you really have code you want to share you can use a private method or suppress the redirect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899670/how-can-i-influence-the-redirect-behavior-in-a-play-controller

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The first approach will be more RESTful. However because of the redirect, the errors and params need to be stored in the cookie to be retrieved.

Since there is a 4k limitation in the data stored in the cookie, this might not be suitable for large forms.